# How to read a text file and store as different variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Inside the text file I currently have:

```
    tickets = []
    ticketPrice = 2.20
    ticketsNo =  150
    income = ticketPrice*ticketsNo
    ticketHi = 54
    limit = 1
    winners = []
    numbers = []
    winningTickets = []
```

How would I now read the file and have it create variables and store values accordingly? I know about

```
    with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        //do stuff
```

but I don't know how to implement it in the fashion I'm after.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hullo there. You could probably go about using a dictionary. You could start off with `f.read().splitlines()` to divide the file into a list of lines. Then split each individual line at the equal sign with `split(' = ')`. You can then store the left-hand-side as the dictionary's key and the right-hand-side as the value. You can parse the constants using `eval()`. With `income = ticketPrice*ticketsNo`, I'm not so sure...

Comment: why don't you just import your file? It's valid Python source code...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How would I do this? I've never heard of importing files before.

Comment: `import myfile`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That gives the following error: 
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import vars.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vars.py'```

Comment: Use `import vars`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga gives same issue? The files are in same directory

Comment: You are going to need to provide more details in the question itself.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga nvm, it was just because I was on an online editor. After transferring files to my Desktop it works. How would I know use those variables? I've tried both ticketPrice and vars.ticketPrice

Comment: if you `import vars` then it should be `vars.ticketPrice`

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'vars' has no attribute 'ticketPrice'`. 
    
    `tickets = []
    ticketPrice = 2.20
    ticketsNo =  150
    income = ticketPrice*ticketsNo
    ticketHi = 54
    limit = 1
    winners = []
    numbers = []
    winningTickets = []`

is my current code (each variable is on a different line, having issues with formatting)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store some varibales out of your main code, I would create a python file with the exact same text you have there, call it `config.py` for example, and them simply import it like:

```
from config import *
```

Even if the file is in a random path you could do

```
sys.path.append("config_path")
from config import *
```

If you just have to execute a random txt and that is the only option, you could use exec, which is **very unrecommended**, so you should think how did you get to that point. But here it is:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    code = file.read()
exec(code, globals())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `assignment unpacking`:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()


tickets, ticketPrice, ticketsNo, income, ticketHi, limit, winners, 
numbers, winningTickets = [d.split('=')[1].split('\n')[0] for d in data]
```

The result of this unpacking will be of type `string`. For int values, you will have to parse the variable eg. `int(limit)`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've formatted this correctly, however I'm getting an error on line 51: `number = r.randint(1, limit)` saying I should be providing a string not an integer? Please see [my code](https://repl.it/repls/CooperativeGratefulSandboxes) for more details (code goes onto more than one document)

Comment: I've tried that code same issue. What I don't get though is why it's saying it should be a string, because on the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) it says to put an integer.

Comment: The variable `limit` that you are trying to put in the `randint()` function is a string, it should be an integer. You have to convert the variable from string to an integer.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the error definitely says that it expected a string and got an integer... The error I get is `TypeError: must be str, not int`