# Create variables from text file in Python

Tags: python, list, variables

This is linked to this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53122621/how-to-read-a-text-file-and-store-as-different-variables-in-python) I used the first answer, I tried changing the code but it didn't seem to work as that example has "[]" in the variables

I have a text file here:

```
room1North = CP
room1East = CP
room1South = OP
room1West = OP
room2North = OP
room2East = CP
room2South = EP
room2West = OP
```

I would like Python to create variables with the values in the text file so the variable "room1North = CP" in Python

I have the following code so far

```
with open("maze files.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()


room1North, room1East, room1South, room1West, room2North, room2Eeast, room2South, room2West  = [d.split('=')[1].split('\n')[0] for d in data]
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You overwrite `data` each time without saving its value, thereby discarding the previous lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: This is not a duplicate because in that example it seems to be doing it from a dictionary inside python rather then have it from a text file

Comment: @thetaken477 re the duplicate, the source data type is not specified in that question

Comment: For debugging your code, try looking at `data`

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually want separate variables; you want a single `dict` whose *keys* are read from the file.

```
with open("maze files.txt", "r") as f:
    data = {k:v for k, v in [line.strip().replace(' ', '').split("=") for line in f]}

# data["room1North"] == "CP"
# data["room1East"] == "CP"
# data["room1South"] == "OP"
# etc
```

Comment: Can you explain further, does this mean I'm declaring in the Python file what the variable is, I want it to use the variable from the text file

Comment: You just use `data["room1North"]` instead of `room1North` in your subsequent code. In general, you don't want your variable names to depend on data from a file (or require the programmer to have advance knowledge of the precise contents of the file).

Comment: how could I test that this code works, If I "print(data["room1North"]) it won't print "CP"

Comment: @thetaken477 this works on my machine, does the snippet give you and IndexError?

Comment: no it gives a ValueError:  `data = {k:v for k, v in [line.strip().replace(' ', '').split("=") for line in f]}
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as bellow

```
with open("maze files.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

room1North, room1East, room1South, room1West, room2North, room2Eeast, room2South, room2West  = [d.split('=')[1].split('\n')[0] for d in ''.join(data).split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have more luck using a dictionary rather than relying on pure variables.

```
with open("maze files.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

rooms = {}
for i in data:
    currentRoom = i.replace(' ', '').strip().split('=')
    rooms[currentRoom[0]] = currentRoom[1]
```

What you'll be left with is a dictionary like the following

```
print(rooms)
#{'room1North ': ' CP', 'room1East ': ' CP', 'room1South ': ' OP', 'room1West ': ' OP', 'room2North ': ' OP', 'room2East ': ' CP', 'room2South ': ' EP', 'room2 West ': ' OP'}
```

You can reference each room and it's value by `rooms["room1North"]`

Comment: That would have been fine but what if I'm using the variable later on, for example if room1North = CP print("you can't go there")

Comment: `if rooms["room1North"] == CP: print("you can't go there")`

Comment: I get an error if I try testing this code: rooms[currentRoom[0]] = currentRoom[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I still get the same error list index out of range on the same line of code

Comment: sounds to me like you instantiated rooms as a list instead of a dictionary, but without seeing the code you're running I don't know.

I'm using python3 and I've copy pasted that code. It runs without error on python 3.6.7

Comment: Im still getting the error I defined the dictionary room via  "= {}", do you have the same txt file as me

Comment: the dictionary is called rooms in my code. not room. I copied the text from your question into a text file.